# Inserting a struct into a vector?

Tags: matlab, vector, struct

I have a 175x1 vector of probabilities, `v`, and a struct with a vector in it, called `data.x`, which is 8156x1 and has numbers from 0-400.

In code provided to me, they do the following:

```
v(data.x);
```

and out comes a vector of 8156x1. I have no idea what it does to the data, and have not been able to recreate the result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your `data.x` is a vector of indexes for your `v` vector. I am surprised that `data.x` has values between 0-400, it will result in error for any value greater than 175 (length of the vector `v`).

For example this:

```
v = [0.4 0.2 0.1 0.44 0.25 0.9 0.91]';
data.x = [1 3 2 5 2]';
v(data.x)

ans =

    0.4000
    0.1000
    0.2000
    0.2500
    0.2000
```